# How to Configure Facebook App For Devise/Omniauth on the current Facebook Apps site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, devise, omniauth

I'm using this tutorial to setup simple OmniAuth authentication with Facebook for my Rails 4 app: http://sleekd.com/tutorials/setting-up-omniauth-authentication-with-facebook/.

The problem is that the tutorial is 3 years old and the organization of the Facebook App config site has changed significantly.

There no longer seems to be a "Site URL" box (where I would input `http://localhost:3000`). I also don't see "Site Domain" box (where I would input `localhost`).

In "Basic Settings" there is a box for "App Domains," but it won't accept `localhost`. Using `localhost` here results in the following error:

> "This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Unity Binary
>   URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL.
>   Check and correct the following domains: localhost"

Can anyone point me to where I should input these two bits of information with the most recent Facebook App config site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go into Settings on left sidebar, then + Add Platform. Choose Website and place

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

in Site Url field.

App Domains field can be blank.